# I have a value in column as Paperback,– 10 Mar 2016 and i want to fetch only Month and Year from it .how should i do it in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have a column called edition and the column values are'Paperback,– 10 Mar 2016' and i want to fetch only month and year from it

I have already tried

```
train_df['Edition_Year'] = train_df['Edition'].str.split(' ').str[3]
```

but all the values are not in the same length so i am not getting properly

Values in the columns are

```
Paperback,– 10 Mar 2016 
Hardcover,– Import, 1 Mar 2018
```

like this

```
train_df['Edition_Year'] = train_df['Edition'].str.split(' ').str[3]
```

I  want to get two columns one for month and another for Year

Answer (score 0):

You can use backwards indexing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['Paperback,– 10 Mar 2016 Hardcover,– Import, 1 Mar 2018'], columns=['Edition'])

print (df)

df['Month'] = df['Edition'].str.split(' ').str[-2] 
df['Year']  = df['Edition'].str.split(' ').str[-1]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
# before
                                             Edition
0  Paperback,– 10 Mar 2016 Hardcover,– Import, 1 ...

# after
                                             Edition Month  Year
0  Paperback,– 10 Mar 2016 Hardcover,– Import, 1 ...   Mar  2018
```

Read more: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)